# How to see computers on LAN in real time?

Tags: networking, lan

I hate it when I connect to any LAN with my windows machine and then I open the Network and you can't see all the computers but you know they are there.

Because when you type in '\\ip-address' or '\\pc-name' and you hit enter it opens it straight away....

Is there any cure for this?
So that whenever a new pc is connected and you hit refresh to see the network all the pcs should be listed at realtime.....

Comment: P.S. I already have SMB client installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master Browsing is unreliable due to the connectivity changes and security in Windows. So you cannot rely on this and must map drives specifically as needed. Microsoft is not enhancing Master Browsing so far as I know

You can use DHCP tools on a Server to see what clients are connected.

Comment: thanks for your answer.... this is more for a local LAN at home... I also have a Linux laptop and a NAS and they almost never show on windows machines.... I need to map them as you said or type in their IP address

Comment: In any network (local or server) Master Browsing is an old concept and increasingly unreliable. Even on my Linux machines I do not see the whole LAN)